# NodeJS sessions, cookies and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, session

I'm trying to build an auth system and I have app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , MemoryStore = require('express').session.MemoryStore
  , app = express();

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', store: new MemoryStore({ reapInterval: 60000 * 10 })}));
app.use(app.router);
```

and the route.index as

```
var express = require('express')
  , mysql = require('mysql')
  , crypto = require('crypto')
  , app = module.exports = express();

app.get('/*',function(req,res){
    var url = req.url.split('/');
    if (url[1] == 'favicon.ico')
        return;

    if (!req.session.user) {
        if (url.length == 4 && url[1] == 'login') {     
            var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                host     : 'localhost',
                user     : 'user',
                password : 'pass',
            });
            var result = null;
            connection.connect();
            connection.query('use database');
            var word = url[3];
            var password = crypto.createHash('md5').update(word).digest("hex");
            connection.query('SELECT id,level FROM users WHERE email = "'+url[2]+'" AND password = "'+password+'"', function(err, rows, fields) {
              if (err) throw err;
                for (i in rows) {
                    result = rows[i].level;
                }
                req.session.user = result;
            });
            connection.end();
        }
    }

console.log(req.session.user)
```

when I access http://mydomain.com/login/user/pass a first time it shows in the last console call  but a second time access the cookie is clean

Comment: Before you do **anything** else, please read up on [proper SQL escaping](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values). What you're doing here is extremely dangerous. You cannot insert arbitrary user-supplied data into your query string. You should always use safe placeholders like `?` to represent the escaped content.

Comment: Yes, after understanding how cookies and sessions works I will manage to protect from sql injection, but now I'm concentrated in understanding sessions and cookies. Tks for the link.

Comment: I just hope you don't promote this code on to the public internet before you figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you not just use Express's session handling? if you use the express command line tool as `express --sessions` it will create the project template with session support. From there you can copy the session lines into your current project. There more information in [How do sessions work in Express.js with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522020/how-do-sessions-work-in-express-with-nodejs) (which this looks like it may be a duplicate of)

As for sanitizing your SQL, you seem to be using the  library, which will santitize your inputs for your if you use parameterized queries (ie, ? placeholders).

Final thing, you are using Express wrong (no offence). Express's router will let you split alot of your routes (along with allowing you to configure the favicon. See [Unable to Change Favicon with Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658035/unable-to-change-favicon-with-express-js) (second answer). 
Using the '/*' route will just catch all GET requests, which greatly limits what the router can do for you.

(continued from comments; putting it here for code blocks)
 Now that you have an app with session support, try **these two routes**:

```
app.get('/makesession', function (req, res) {
    req.session.message = 'Hello world';
    res.end('Created session with message : Hello world');
});
app.get('/getsession', function (req, res) {
    if (typeof req.session.message == 'undefined') {
        res.end('No session');
    } else {
        res.end('Session message: '+req.session.message);
    }
});
```

If you navigate in your browser to /makesession, it will set a session message and notify you that it did. Now if you navigate to /getsession, it will send you back the session message if it exists, or else it will tell you that the session does not exist.

Comment: I created the app with session support. About the mysql, this app is just for tests and I'm trying to understand how the routes work also. For routing I have "subapp = require('./routes/subapp')" and "app.use(subapp);" where inside that subapp I have the get "/subapp"

Comment: I assume you edited your question since then, as I no longer see you trying to set a cookie. I assume then that it's working now?

Comment: Nick, still the same problem. Now I installed a new app with "express --sessions sessao" and inserted in the routes/index.js the line "res.cookie('session', 'user', 'teste');" and in routes/user.js file the line "console.log(req.session)" and the console.log didn't have the req.session.user value

Comment: Express will handle the cookies for you. Remove the cookie lines. I'm going to add something into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your cookie value in the **response** object:

```
res.cookie('session', 'user', result);
```

http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie

Comment: Hector I replaced that line with yours and now gives me this error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: You probably already issues are res.send(). The call to set the cookie should be before that call. If I were you I would create a smaller version of your code to understand cookies and Express and then mix the DB access.

Comment: I had a res.end() outside the result of the mysql that was causing that error but even when I put inside the mysql result the cookie in the second access is still empty. { cookie:  { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true } }