# no request for favicon

Tags: html, node.js, favicon

I am writing a simple node.js file server using node's http module (I am not using EXPRESS).

I noticed my initial GET request is firing and all subsequent GET request are being made for the css and javascript; however, I am not getting a request for the favicon. Even when I look at at page inspector, I don't have any errors and the favicon is not showing up in the resources.

**HTML**

```
// Inside the head of index.html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

**node.JS**

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){

    // log each req method
    console.log(`${req.method} request for ${req.url}`);

}).listen(3000)
```

There is a default icon that is a mustache, but not my custom icon. What am I missing here?

Just in case it's relevant to the question. I am using node v4.2.4

**Edit**

I think it has something to do with how I am reading and serving the file.

```
if ( req.url.match(/.ico$/) ){
    var icoPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url);
    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(icoPath, "BINARY");
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/x-icon"});
    fileStream.pipe(res)
```

Should I not be using a readstream? Is the encoding Binary or utf-8 or something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9943801/1848109 this could help you and https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Comment: Hmmm, not helpful. Like i said it works locally. But when serving the page from node. no request is made for it.

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue. Clear browser cache?

Comment: @aaron, yea no more mustache icon, but still no request for the favicon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I played around with your repo code and did some changes to see if I can serve my `favicon` or not. I found out some strange stuff:

- `favicon` serving is tricky and mysterious (my point of view)
- Chrome used to have a bug or might still have relating to favicon (Google please, there are many results)
- Seems like browser caches `favicon`, force refresh and different methods used to make browser get the new/updated `favicon`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)
- I found that once Chrome browser is served the favicon then in the subsequent request, there is no more favicon request. Not until you change the `href` of `favicon` in your `html` file and that forces browser to make a fresh request.

I copied bit/pieces of your code to reproduce the issue and got it working. I decided to serve the `favicon` differently see below:

**server.js**

```
if(req.url.match("/requestFavicon") ){
    var img = fs.readFileSync('public/favicon.ico');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon' });
    res.end(img, 'binary');
}
```

**index.html**

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/requestFavicon"/>
```

Did a `nodemon server.js` and used Chrome browser to make `http://192.168.1.18:8080` request. The `terminal` showed the following:

```
GET request for /
GET request for /requestFavicon
```

And the `favicon.ico` (tiny vehicle .ico taken from [here](http://www.freefavicon.com/freefavicons/objects/iconinfo/car-152-232990.html)) displayed in the browser see below:

[image]

After the above `favicon` was displayed, any subsequent `http://192.1668.18:8080` produced no request for `favicon` but, only displayed the following request in terminal of nodejs

```
GET request for /
```

Similarly no `favicon` related request in the browser developer tool network tab.

At this point, I assumed that the browser has cached it and does not request at all because it already has it. So I googled and came across this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463199/how-to-set-custom-favicon-in-node-js-express) to force refresh favicon request. So, let's change the `favicon` href in the `index.html` (and `server.js`) and retry

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/updatedRequestFavicon"/>
```

Now retry access `http://192.168.1.18:8080` and watch for nodejs terminal as well as chrome developer console and I get the following:

```
GET request for /
GET request for /UpdatedRequestFavicon
```

[image]

Now I want to totally change the `favicon` and put a new one. I added [this](http://www.freefavicon.com/freefavicons/objects/iconinfo/cartoon-sun-152-194877.html) one updated the `server.js` and refreshed the browser. Surprisingly no console log in nodejs (for new `favicon`), no request in browser developer tools newtork console (so served the cached value then).

To force the browser to get the new `favicon`,  I want to change the `href` of `favicon` in `index.html` and and update the `server.js` with new href and then see if brwoser gets forced to request for updated favicon or keep using the cached one.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/NewFavicon"/>
if(req.url.match("/NewFavicon") ){
    var img = fs.readFileSync('public/favicon_new.ico');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon' });
    res.end(img, 'binary');
 }
```

Changed. Changes reloaded by nodemon, refresh the browser and here is the result:

```
GET request for /
GET request for /NewFavicon
```

[image]

Your issue could be related to

1. Browser already has a cached favicon hence, does not request it
2. You are not serving the favicon properly in server.js
3. Something else

If you want to test my code, feel free, here is the **server.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // Log req Method
    console.log(`${req.method} request for ${req.url}`);
  //res.writeHead(200);
  //res.end('index.html');

    // Serve html, js, css and img
    if ( req.url === "/" ){
        fs.readFile("index.html", "UTF-8", function(err, html){
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            res.end(html);
        });
    }

    if(req.url.match("/NewFavicon") ){
        console.log('Request for favicon.ico');

        var img = fs.readFileSync('public/favicon_new.ico');
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon' });
        res.end(img, 'binary');

        //var icoPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url);
        //var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(icoPath, "base64");
        //res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/x-icon"});
        //fileStream.pipe(res);
    }
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Here is **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>nodeCAST</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/NewFavicon"/>
  <!--<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">-->
</head>
<body>
  <p>I am the index.html</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I placed the favicon.ico under /public directory. Good luck.

**EDIT**

**Tested with Chrome Browser Version 47.0.2526.111 m**

**Node v4.2.4**

Comment: Dang, that is a lot of information. I figured something peculiar was going on. I will try it out and get back to you soon.

Comment: It worked! So i was using a read stream and piping the results to the response. readFileSync and the binary encoding seemed to be something I was missing. Thanks for the help! I was begining to regret my decision to offer a bounty on this question, but faith is restored. cheers!

Comment: Glad your issue is resolved and as far as bounty is concerned, hopefully you will get a few more upvote to this question. It is nice and I learned a lot when trying to answering it.

Answer (score 0):

The browser makes the request to `favicon.ico` itself, automatically, *when the page is loaded.* This code, which `end`s the `res`ponse, will receive the favicon request:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url}`);
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

As you can see in the log of running it:

```
GET /
GET /favicon.ico
```

Comment: Thats just it, I don't see a get request for the favicon.ico when I load the page. Everything else makes a request.

Comment: You don't see the request in the log? That doesn't make sense, with the program I have here.. hmm..

Comment: Yea, You can see my code on my [github](https://github.com/mattgreenberg/matthew_greenberg_portfolio/tree/master/week3/forecast_server)