# Can't get rid of jenkins favicon

Tags: node.js, jenkins, favicon, html-webpack-plugin

I'm running Jenkins behind nginx on my server. I have an app built in NodeJS and it uses the [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin). I've set the favicon and it displays the correct image locally but on the server it does not update the Jenkins logo favicon. Here's how I set it:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'myTpl.html',
    ...
    ...
    favicon: 'myImages/logo.png'
  })
```

I need to get rid of the Jenkins logo favicon and I can not find anything related to this in the Jenkins dashboard. Anybody got any tips?

Thanks

Comment: node has a weird way of cacheing your favicon. To force a change on it hit f5 (sometimes works) or change the filename of your favicon (always works). Try changing the name to 'myImages/logonew.png'. That will force the update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no request for favicon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918906/no-request-for-favicon)

Comment: You can add a query string to you file name. For example: `favicon.ico?v=2`. The browser will treat this as new Image and ignore the cached favicon.ico.