# Express js prevent GET /favicon.ico

Tags: node.js, express

In every request, my server is receiving GET request to /favicon.ico, even when it's REST api that not include html file. Why is this happening and how can I prevent this request?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Browsers will by default try to request `/favicon.ico` from the root of a hostname, in order to show an icon in the browser tab.

If you want to avoid this request returning a 404, you can either:

- Supply a `favicon.ico` file that is available at the root of your site.
- Use a module such as [serve-favicon](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-favicon) to point requests to a specific file.
- Catch the `favicon.ico` request and send a `204 No Content` status:

```
app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => res.status(204));
```

Comment: I submitted an edit to the above response indicating that sending a `204` response is more appropriate than a `200`.

Comment: In Express 4, `res.sendStatus(204);`

Comment: `sendStatus(204)` doesn't really make sense. [`sendStatus`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendStatus) purpose is set response body matching the status code. In case of 204, there is no response body. Just do `res.status(204).end()`.

Comment: `app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => res.status(204).end());` is what I ended up using, works perfectly, clean and makes sense.

Answer (score 33):

my preferred method is middleware

put this somewhere:

```
function ignoreFavicon(req, res, next) {
  if (req.originalUrl.includes('favicon.ico')) {
    res.status(204).end()
  }
  next();
}
```

then:

```
app.use(ignoreFavicon);
```

Comment: The 204 status code means "no content", yet you're serving JSON. It should be a response length of 0.

Comment: A more appropriate response would be `res.status(204).end()`

Comment: @camaulay noted

Comment: got  "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". Fixed it by moving next() in else condition.

Comment: these 204 errors end up not showing a favicon on the page

Answer (score 8):

I agree with @Blair Anderson that middleware is the best course of action here but `204` [should not return a body](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5). Also, you may want to catch *all* favicon request e.g.: https://example.com/some/path/favicon.ico. In which case something like this works best:

```
app.use( function(req, res, next) {

  if (req.originalUrl && req.originalUrl.split("/").pop() === 'favicon.ico') {
    return res.sendStatus(204);
  }

 next();
  
});
```

Comment: Since the request for a favicon does not always come in the form of **favicon.ico**, you might do this instead for the second half of the && expression: **req.originalUrl.split('/').pop().includes('favicon'))**. Note that I'm using ES6 for **includes**, for ES5, use **indexof**.

Comment: why do you use return statements?

Comment: @user210757, you don't need a return. Not sure why I put that there but it won't hurt. I've updated the function

Answer (score 3):

In Case of **web apps**, we should supply a favicon.ico from static resources either serving directly via vanilla or by making use of express middleware [serve-favicon](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-favicon.html)

In the case of **API apps**, we should supply 204 (no content) status code which will result in a success roundtrip.

We can make use of `sendStatus()` method to respond with status code 204 (no content)

```
app.get('/favicon.ico', function(req, res) { 
    res.sendStatus(204); 
});
```

if you are using `status(204)` make sure to use `end()` as well.
Otherwise, the request will remain in pending status.

```
app.get('/favicon.ico', function(req, res) { 
    res.status(204);
    res.end();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers seem to assume you don't want to see a favicon, and they work but no favicon shows. My problem was with using an expressjs router with a parameter after a forward slash:

```
/mint/:number
```

The first call to it would get the correct number in the paramter, like mint/1005, number would be 1005.

But then the browser tries to get the favicon on that subroute, so it calls:

```
/mint/favicon.ico
```

This results in the number parameter being set to 'favicon.ico'. To catch this, instead of returning 204, it needs to return the static file for that route, so for now I just put a specific route to catch that case, and redirect it to the root favicon.ico (which is in the public folder).  Any improvements on this are welcome:

```
app.get('/mint/favicon.ico', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico');
});
```