# Node Express app.get(*) req.url is always /favion.ico

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, server

I have an Express server, where my app is served from the `app.get('*')` route.

I'd like to have users with promo codes visit the site from a campaign URL like so: `www.mysite.com/?code=123`.

The problem is every browser request is routed to the favicon request, thus my `req.url` and `req.query` variables cannot be used to get the promo codes. `Req.url` is always `/favicon.ico` and `req.query` is always empty.

I did find the original URL is the request object's header, but this seems like a roundabout way of achieving my objective. The request object's original URL field also points to `favicon.ico`.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.url);
  console.log(req.query);
}
```

I'd like to keep my promo code solution as quick and dirty as possible for the time being, so I'm fine with URL parameters. Is there a simple solution to extract the original URL query parameters without diving into the headers?

EDIT: I'm now sharing my root request handler below. The favicon request is handled by the express-favicon middleware earlier in the code.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log("In get *");
  console.log("Req.url: ",req.url);
  console.log("Promo code: ",req.query.promo);
  const context = {};
    const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
        <App />
      </StaticRouter>
    );

  const indexFile = path.resolve('./public/index.html');

  fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
        return res.status(500).send('Oops, better luck next time!');
      }

      return res.send(
        data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${app}</div>`)
      );
    });
})
```

Comment: I think you should try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35408810/4518930

Comment: @AdilLiaqat that didn't work.

    app.get('/favicon.ico',(req,res)=>{

      console.log("In get /favicon");
      res.sendStatus(204);
    });

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    
      console.log("In get *");
    ...//serve the React app
})

Only the log from get /favicon gets printed. Weirdly enough, the app is served from get *, so it must be getting executed somehow. But the console log must get redirected elsewhere.

Comment: And... where is this magic favicon route that's apparently intercepting everything? Are you sure hits to the promo page aren't both causing a request to the favicon AND the promo page? because... that's how browsers typically work.

Comment: @KevinB I've tried using both an explicit favicon request handler, and middleware that handles the request. In both cases, the favicon is returned, the web app gets served, but the req.query URL is empty in the root get request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I'm using React Router, which doesn't support query parameters:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/query-parameters

To get aroud this, I'm using `window.location.search` on the client to get the promo code, then passing to the backend with an explicit promo handler.

Answer (score -1):

You can accept dynamic value as part of the URL in express

api call ==>  `www.mysite.com/dynamic_promo_code`

```
app.get('/:promo_code',(req,res)=>{
// req.params will be and object holding your dynamic promo_code
const promo = req.params.promo_code; // this will be your dynamic promo code
});
```

if you wish your promo code is opitional and don't want to be part of URL

api call ==> `www.mysite.com?promocode=dynamic_promo_code`

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  //req.query is an object holding your optional parameter
  const code = req.query.promocode; // this will be yor dynamic promo code
})
```

Comment: This is more or less what I'm doing now. The problem is that the favicon request hijacks the call, then reroutes to the intended URL with the URL the user entered in the header. I'm going to try to solve this with middleware.

Comment: you can place your favicon route above these routes. or you can share your code so that I can help

Comment: Thanks. I'll share my code above. I've placed the favicon route above these. The facvicon route gets called, then the request gets forwarded to the root call with the original URL masked. I am now using middleware to handle the favicon, but the same thing is happening.

Comment: your entire code please with favicon and promo code

Comment: any particular reason to use app.get(*)? * is basically used for wild card entry so it will be executed for a favicon too. so keeping separate handler for each request will work.

Comment: I get the exact same results with app.get("/") as I do app.get("*").

Comment: app.get('/', handler...) will get executed only for empty route and get request, but your app.get('*', handler...) will execute for any get request regardless of URL.