# Why I am getting Favicon request in chrome with Node js And Express? How can I prevent from Favicon request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do prevent favicon request in Goolge chrome as I am getting 2 requests?

```
const express= require('express');
const app=express();
const port=3000;
app.use((req , res , next)=>{
    console.log("In the Middleware");
    next();
});
app.use((req , res , next)=>{
    console.log("In the Other Middleware");
    res.send("<h1>Hello From Express</h1>");
});
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('App running at port '+port);
});
```

**What should I do please help?**

Comment: Several browsers make this request automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Chrome searching for my favicon.ico when I serve up a file from ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003350/why-is-chrome-searching-for-my-favicon-ico-when-i-serve-up-a-file-from-asp-net-m)

Comment: How do i prevent this ? this is so annoying while working as beginner , or this is okay to work as this is doing?

Comment: Try searching this site: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35408810/1427161

Comment: This usually isn't a problem if you don't send a response on EVERY possible path like you are doing.  That's probably just not a good server design.  Instead, configure specific routes for specific paths and then use a default 404 handler that will catch all other routes and send a 404 response for them.  Then, the request for the favicon.ico won't end up triggering some action you don't expect.

Comment: Okay Thank You So Much