# Loading a favicon in chrome in a new window with a url of http://localhost/:[port]/

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome, express

In my javascript I open a new window (page B) when a user clicks on a button on page A, and everything is working as expected on page B except that the favicon is not showing up (in chrome it doesn't appear, on firefox it works fine). The tag appears to be correct, and when I put the href val for the favicon in the browser the favicon is showing as expected (attached image).

There is an [answer from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome) to another question that is very similar, although I was hoping a new solution might have been figured out since then, and that solution isn't going to work for my goal.

I could upload the favicon to a site (non-local), but this won't work if I wanted to make my favicon dynamic (which I do).

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost:3000/images/favicon.png">
```

[image]

I am using node and express and [tried this setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463199/how-to-set-custom-favicon-in-express) as well, but this only works on Page A, and not Page B:

```
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.png')));
```

Are there any other strategies that the SO community has figured out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way it should work

```
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');

app.use(favicon(path.resolve('public/favicon.ico')));
```

Comment: thanks, your code does work on Page A, but not on the new window, Page B.