# express.js favicons not showing up

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, favicon, iisnode

I'm currently running a simple express.js example just trying to get favicons working. Everything works fine locally but when I upload it to my production server it just shows the default favicon. I've tried clearing the cache but the production server favicon seems to not want to show up. I'm running everything on iisnode on a windows 2008 aws server.

Anyone know what the problem might be?

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//for favicon
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');



app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/views/icons/favicon.ico'));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname, 'views'));
});


app.listen(port);
console.log("full path is: " + (__dirname + '/views/icons/favicon.ico'));
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Comment: There is a similar post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658035/unable-to-change-favicon-with-express-js?rq=1

Comment: It looks like you require('serve-favicon') but you're using express.favicon() instead.  Note that if you're using express 4, express.favicon() won't be available

Comment: Also `app.configure()` no longer exists in Express 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the favicon middleware and then do:

```
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico'));
```

Or better, using the path module:

```
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname,'public','images','favicon.ico'));
```

(note that this solution will work in express 3 apps as well)

**Removed in Express 4 : app.configure()**

`app.configure()` is no longer available. Refer to [this](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#appconfigure) for more info.

Comment: Note that the latter use with path.join is missing a final `)` parentheses on the right.

Answer (score 2):

sometimes it take longer time to show up in browser. Try to clean cache or try another browser and refresh multiple time.

Answer (score 0):

Install dependencies `serve-favicon` and `path` from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-favicon), and update index.js accordingly.

```
//import packages
var favicon = require('serve-favicon'), path = require("path");
//use favicon icon path to access in application.
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname+'/favicon.ico')));
```

Refresh the browser to reflect the favicon.