# Why doesn't my favicon get served?

Tags: express, favicon

I am using Express and serve-favicon middleware.

```
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'))
```

I am using this command right after the express app has been initialized. I have placed the favicon in the public directory. Why does it not work?

My problem is not unique but it still does not work.

Comment: Does it show an error when you inspect it? Typically it will say something about the image not being found and it will show the path it is looking in, have you verified it is looking at the correct path?

Comment: Is there anything on console?

Comment: Nothing on the console.

Comment: How can I verify it's looking at the correct path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Change Favicon with Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658035/unable-to-change-favicon-with-express-js)

Comment: Can you give is the full js code?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/a3D6xg

Comment: @Rob, that is not good as can't open the favicon in the browser